# Is the "fb:admins" meta tag deprecated in favor for "fb:app_id" or can it still be used if there is no Facebook app?

Tags: facebook, meta-tags, referrer

I am trying to migrate an old site to a new site.
In the homepage of the old site `https://www.example.com`, I see the following line:

```
<meta property="fb:admins" content="#####" />
```

The homepage has a link point to the Facebook page for the company, like this: `https://www.facebook.com/MyCompany`

I asked Yoast SEO whether they will support this tag. But [they said](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/can-yoast-seo-add-fbadmins-tag-to-a-page/#new-topic-0) that `fb:admins` is not supported and I should use `fb:app_id` instead. However, I search for document on `fb:app_id` and it seems this attribute is for those who develops an application for Facebook. For my case, I do not have any such applications at all.

I try to study the meaning of `fb:admins`. It seems that this property contains several Facebook ID that can access the insight data. So if I understand correct, with the inclusion of `fb:admins` attribute, the administrator with the specific ID that see how many visits to the Facebook page come from the site, like the referrer info in Google Analytics. Is that correct?

Comment: You can get more info on that here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10836135/when-do-i-need-a-fbapp-id-or-fbadmins

Comment: @LuisAlbertoBarandiaran, THank you. I have read that post before posting mine. The post explains the usage of fb:admins, which makes me think it is useful. But there are no informaton about ceasing support of fb:admins in Facebook.

Comment: I believe that Yoast posting maybe inaccurate. I have checked the Facebook Dev documentation, and there is no mention of that tag being deprecated, on the contrary, it explicitly tells you how to use it. Check under "Assign a Facebook Account as Admin": https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/comments/